# LoadLibraryExA: The loaded DLL uses another DLL, which seems to use LoadLibrary and fails

Tags: c, windows, dll, sdl-2

I am writing a small programming language interpreter on Windows 7. It has an "extension module" mechanism, triggered when the programmer says `import something`.

And "extension module" is a DLL (in this case `something.dll`). It is loaded by the interpreter using `LoadLibraryExA`.

The DLL may be dynamically linked to other DLLs (by load-time linking, *not* using `LoadLibrary`).

I'm loading the extension module this way:

```
HMODULE handle = LoadLibraryExA(path, NULL, LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS | LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR);
```

Generally this works :) I simply place any DLL that the extension module uses, in the same directory as the extension module.

The problem seems to arise, when a dependency of the extension module tries to use `LoadLibrary` to load another DLL during runtime.

**My concrete issue:**

I have written an extension module which is a wrapper around the `SDL2.dll` and `SDL2_image.dll` libraries.

Internally, `SDL2_image.dll` apparently uses something like `LoadLibrary` to load `libpng16-16.dll`. It does so when the extension module calls `IMG_Init()`. `IMG_Init()` fails, and `IMG_GetError()` returns this string:

```
Failed loading libpng16-16.dll: The specified module could not be found.
```

This is the directory structure:

```
interpreter.exe (the main executable, started from a CWD somewhere else in the computer)
   /stdlib
      (Loaded by the executable using LoadLibraryExA)
      extension_module.dll
    
      (Loaded for extension_module.dll by the OS directly during load time)
      SDL2.dll
      SDL2_image.dll

      (Trying to be loaded dynamically by SDL2_image.dll during runtime)
      libpng16-16.dll
      zlib1.dll
```

As mentioned, `extension_module.dll` is loaded successfully along with its dependencies `SDL2.dll` and `SDL2_image.dll`. The failure occurs when `extension_module.dll` tries to call `IMG_Init()` on `SDL2_image.dll`.

This is fixed when I add the full path to the `stdlib` directory to the `PATH`.

However: I would like to be able to simply execute `interpreter.exe` from anywhere in the computer, and have everything work.

I desire a "self contained" solution - where the only thing I need to do for an extension module, is to put it and all of its recursive dependencies in the `stdlib` directory.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Looks like [SetDllDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectorya) does what you wanted. Aside from that, you can modify PATH with `setenv`